# Data not getting to node server to client side Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

Problem :-

I want to insert the data from the form and display all the data back to the data grid. Currently, I can properly inserting and retrieving data from the database, but could not send it to client ajax call.

1. I have one client file **posts.ejs** and one backend node file called **app.js(server file)**.
2. I want to send data back to the server to client ajax response.

I have tried multiple solutions but did not get the best solutions.
I hope you guys will help to solve this problem.

**App.js (Server file)**

```
    var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mysql = require("mysql");

    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use( bodyParser.json());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    app.post("/posts",  function (req, res) {
        console.log("Posts Api called from Admin.!");

    var sql = "INSERT INTO post_master (title, description, user_id, created_by, comments, category, created_date) " +
        "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    connection.query(sql, [req.body.news_title, req.body.description, null,null, null, null, req.body.news_date ], function (err, res) {
        if(err){
            console.log("Something went wrong while inserting data.!");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Data successfully inserted.!");
            // I want to load all data and return back to ajax call.
            var fetchPosts = "select * from user_master where user_name= ? AND password= ?";
            connection.query(fetchPosts, function (err, posts) {
                console.log("Data successfully fetch and passing to ajax call back.!");

                // Error while sending 
                res.send(posts); // Error :- res.send is not a valid function.
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Posts.ejs**

```
var requestMedia = $.ajax({
            url: "/posts",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(postData),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            headers: headerSetting
        });
         // Not getting data from server app.js file.
         requestMedia.done(function (data) {
            console.log("Ajax post response  data : " + data);
            return;
        });
        requestMedia.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("fail");
            return
        });
```

If you have still any problem to understand the problem then let me know.

Comment: Still looking for a fix?

Comment: @funcoding, yes looking for solution.